# Terminal server cannot load user's profiles

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

Terminal server is not loading profiles; it is possible to log in with a default profile, but many things would be missing. Error message reported insuffucient resources. Noticed several terminal sessions had initial login over a month ago. Restarted some services with large memory consumption (but not large enough to cause problems) Discovered virtual memory was on manual, and returned to system managed. No improvement.

Windows Terminal Server 2003 in user licensing mode; most all clients are Widnows XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented changes to pool settings recommended in [KB935649](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=935649)  However, this required restarting the server, which probably would have cleared a resource error anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers UPHClean to help track down any memory leak issues in User Profiles.  I've had some success with the tool (other times it wasn't a help).

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1B286E6D-8912-4E18-B570-42470E2F3582&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

We've seen this due to a memory leak in some application or component (such as AV or backup agent software). We usually have had to restart the server. Have you done this? You mentioned restarting services, but not the server itself.

Comment: "Restarting the server" meant the machine.  I just changed AV packages, so that might take care of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is permissions. I know the error says resources, but this seems more like a permissions thing to me. Just for giggles make everyone (or a select few) an admin (don't forget to turn this off) and see if your problem disappears. If it does, then permissions is your culprit.